# фильтр внутри групп по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется фрейм данных:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'фрукт': ['груша','груша','арбуз','банан','груша', 'груша', 'вишня', 'груша', 'вишня', 'абрикос', 'груша', 'груша', 'банан'],
'страна': ['россия','сша', 'россия', 'россия', np.nan, np.nan,'россия', 'франция', 'португалия', 'россия', np.nan, np.nan, 'россия'],
'id': ['01','01','01','011', '011', '011', '011', '6', '6', '5', '5', '5', '5'],
'месяц': ['март','июнь','январь','январь', 'январь', 'январь', 'январь', 'январь', 'январь', 'январь', 'январь', 'сентябрь', 'апрель']        
}
dates = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['фрукт','страна', 'id', 'месяц'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно в каждой `id` группе удалить строки, где `(страна == Россия и месяц != январь)`.

Как можно это сделать?

Ожидаемый результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инвертируем условие удаления, чтобы знать, какие данные нам нужно сохранить/выбрать. При этом `==` превращается в `!=` и наоборот, а `и` превращается в `или` (и наоборот). Воспользуемся `.loc` для выборки и не забываем использовать скобки и побитовые операции `и`/`или` между получающимися в скобках булевыми масками.

```
df = dates.loc[(dates.страна != 'россия') | (dates.месяц == 'январь')].reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3):

Вариант 1:

```
res = df.drop(df.query("страна == 'россия' and месяц != 'январь'").index)
```

Вариант 2:

```
res = df.query("страна != 'россия' or месяц == 'январь'")
```